# Pandas - Can you back fill conditionally on another column while skipping rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I need to backfill a value 7 places, but I don't want to do it unless a different column has a value greater than 0 in it. Is this possible with Pandas? The last row with a 1 in `Reason` is the original row with a 1 obviously.

The code I'm using right now to get the back fill 7 places:

```
s = df.Reason.bfill(limit=7)
s.loc[s.notnull() & df.Reason.isnull()] = 1
df['Reason'] = s
```

Outputs like this:

```
Time Stamp              HP_1H_mean  Reason
2019-07-26 07:00:00     410.637966  0.0
2019-07-26 08:00:00     403.521735  0.0
2019-07-26 09:00:00     403.143925  0.0
2019-07-26 10:00:00     410.542895  0.0
2019-07-26 11:00:00     396.896670  0.0
2019-07-26 12:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 13:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 14:00:00     399.929812  0.0
2019-07-26 15:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 16:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 17:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 18:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 19:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 20:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 21:00:00     390.811179  0.0
2019-07-26 22:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 23:00:00     395.659520  0.0
2019-07-27 00:00:00     0.000000    1.0
2019-07-27 01:00:00     0.000000    1.0
2019-07-27 02:00:00     0.000000    1.0
2019-07-27 03:00:00     0.000000    1.0
2019-07-27 04:00:00     0.000000    1.0
2019-07-27 05:00:00     267.144639  1.0
2019-07-27 06:00:00     266.619800  1.0
2019-07-27 07:00:00     296.005934  1.0
2019-07-27 08:00:00     288.335720  0.0
```

I've tried variations like `s.loc[s.notnull() & df.Reason.isnull() & df.HP_1H_mean != 0] = 1` and although these do not throw an exception, it does not work.

Expected output:

```
Time Stamp              HP_1H_mean  Reason
2019-07-26 07:00:00     410.637966  0.0
2019-07-26 08:00:00     403.521735  0.0
2019-07-26 09:00:00     403.143925  0.0
2019-07-26 10:00:00     410.542895  1.0
2019-07-26 11:00:00     396.896670  1.0
2019-07-26 12:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 13:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 14:00:00     399.929812  1.0
2019-07-26 15:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 16:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 17:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 18:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 19:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 20:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 21:00:00     390.811179  1.0
2019-07-26 22:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-26 23:00:00     395.659520  1.0
2019-07-27 00:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-27 01:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-27 02:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-27 03:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-27 04:00:00     0.000000    0.0
2019-07-27 05:00:00     267.144639  1.0
2019-07-27 06:00:00     266.619800  1.0
2019-07-27 07:00:00     296.005934  1.0
2019-07-27 08:00:00     288.335720  0.0
```

Comment: What does your input dataframe look like?  Is there 1 in reason for the last row and the rest or zeroes or NaN?

Comment: @Ben.T I just tried this, it made sense, but did not work. Still looking like the output above with consecutive rows having 1

Comment: @ScottBoston The input df is the same as the first one posted, except there's only a 1 in teh second to last row, and 0's in everything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use pandas intrinsic data alignment to help with this:  First boolean select rows where 'HP_1H_mean' is greater than zero, use `bfill` with `limit=7` and assign this back to the full column.  pandas will align the data base on the indexes.  Lastly, `fillna` with zero.

<strike>df['Reason'] = df.loc[df['HP_1H_mean'] > 0, 'Reason'].bfill(limit=7)</strike>

Update if zeroes exists in 'Reason' already then `mask` those zeroes

```
df['Reason'] = df.loc[df['HP_1H_mean'] > 0, 'Reason'].mask(df['Reason'] != 1).bfill(limit=7)

df['Reason'] = df['Reason'].fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          Time     Stamp  HP_1H_mean  Reason
0   2019-07-26  07:00:00  410.637966     0.0
1   2019-07-26  08:00:00  403.521735     0.0
2   2019-07-26  09:00:00  403.143925     0.0
3   2019-07-26  10:00:00  410.542895     1.0
4   2019-07-26  11:00:00  396.896670     1.0
5   2019-07-26  12:00:00    0.000000     0.0
6   2019-07-26  13:00:00    0.000000     0.0
7   2019-07-26  14:00:00  399.929812     1.0
8   2019-07-26  15:00:00    0.000000     0.0
9   2019-07-26  16:00:00    0.000000     0.0
10  2019-07-26  17:00:00    0.000000     0.0
11  2019-07-26  18:00:00    0.000000     0.0
12  2019-07-26  19:00:00    0.000000     0.0
13  2019-07-26  20:00:00    0.000000     0.0
14  2019-07-26  21:00:00  390.811179     1.0
15  2019-07-26  22:00:00    0.000000     0.0
16  2019-07-26  23:00:00  395.659520     1.0
17  2019-07-27  00:00:00    0.000000     0.0
18  2019-07-27  01:00:00    0.000000     0.0
19  2019-07-27  02:00:00    0.000000     0.0
20  2019-07-27  03:00:00    0.000000     0.0
21  2019-07-27  04:00:00    0.000000     0.0
22  2019-07-27  05:00:00  267.144639     1.0
23  2019-07-27  06:00:00  266.619800     1.0
24  2019-07-27  07:00:00  296.005934     1.0
25  2019-07-27  08:00:00  288.335720     0.0
```

Comment: Somehow your code didn't give me the same output with yours. There are still `0` at `2019-07-26 10:00:00` and `11:00:00`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I started with all zeroes except the final 1.  The run this code.

Answer (score 0):

I want to try something different, so I use reverse `cummax`, `cumsum` and pick row 1 to 8 on the slicing of `Reason`. Finally , update it back to `df`

```
s = (df.loc[df.HP_1H_mean.gt(0), 'Reason'][::-1].cummax().cumsum()
                                                .between(1, 8).astype(int)[::-1])
df.update(s)

Out[675]:
            Time_Stamp  HP_1H_mean  Reason
0  2019-07-26 07:00:00  410.637966     0.0
1  2019-07-26 08:00:00  403.521735     0.0
2  2019-07-26 09:00:00  403.143925     0.0
3  2019-07-26 10:00:00  410.542895     1.0
4  2019-07-26 11:00:00  396.896670     1.0
5  2019-07-26 12:00:00    0.000000     0.0
6  2019-07-26 13:00:00    0.000000     0.0
7  2019-07-26 14:00:00  399.929812     1.0
8  2019-07-26 15:00:00    0.000000     0.0
9  2019-07-26 16:00:00    0.000000     0.0
10 2019-07-26 17:00:00    0.000000     0.0
11 2019-07-26 18:00:00    0.000000     0.0
12 2019-07-26 19:00:00    0.000000     0.0
13 2019-07-26 20:00:00    0.000000     0.0
14 2019-07-26 21:00:00  390.811179     1.0
15 2019-07-26 22:00:00    0.000000     0.0
16 2019-07-26 23:00:00  395.659520     1.0
17 2019-07-27 00:00:00    0.000000     0.0
18 2019-07-27 01:00:00    0.000000     0.0
19 2019-07-27 02:00:00    0.000000     0.0
20 2019-07-27 03:00:00    0.000000     0.0
21 2019-07-27 04:00:00    0.000000     0.0
22 2019-07-27 05:00:00  267.144639     1.0
23 2019-07-27 06:00:00  266.619800     1.0
24 2019-07-27 07:00:00  296.005934     1.0
25 2019-07-27 08:00:00  288.335720     0.0
```